# How to dump a table to a text file in SQL server? in sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, export

How to export a table to a text file?

I need to get the INSERT script (structure and data) for an already existing table.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server, the method is differnt depending onthe version.

Comment: @Gokul: I was only assuming you needed both structure and data. Feel free to change that bit if I wasn't right.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL2k, try to read about bulk copy, the command should be **bcp** i think

examples from MS help file has something like ...

Exporting data from table to text file

```
bcp "SELECT au_fname, au_lname FROM pubs..authors ORDER BY au_lname" queryout Authors.txt -c -Sservername -Usa -Ppassword
```

Importing data from text file to table:

The command to bulk copy data from Newpubs.dat into publishers2 is:

```
bcp pubs..publishers2 in newpubs.dat -c -t , -r \n -Sservername -Usa -Ppassword
```

Alternatively, you can use the BULK INSERT statement from a query tool, such as SQL Query Analyzer, to bulk copy data:

```
BULK INSERT pubs..publishers2 FROM 'c:\newpubs.dat'
WITH (
   DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Gath

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2005 Management Studio, you can use the Import/Export Wizard (not sure if you specifically needed a script, or simply a way to export the structure/data to a file, but this suggestion will do it without an actual script):

- right-click on the database containing the table
- select Tasks->Export Data
- Choose a Data Source screen: (after the welcome screen) leave defaulted values, click Next
- Choose a Destination: "Flat File Destination" for the Destination field.  Then fill in the file name/path and the other options as you wish, click Next
- Select Copy data..., click Next
- Select the table to export, click Next
- On the Save and Execute Package screen, you can just leave Execute Immediately selected, or if you'd like to save the resulting "script" as a SSIS package you can select that option also.  Click Next, then Finish, to execute the export
- Your resulting file will have the contents of the table.  If you then need to "insert" this data into a different db you can use the "Import Data" option of the Wizard to import the data from the text file into the other database/table.

Comment: thanks..
it showing.. 
        Warning 0x80047076: Data Flow Task   &
        Error 0xc00470fe:

Comment: 0x80047076 is just a warning so you can ignore it.  However, 0xc00470fe looks like it was a bug but is fixed in SP1.  Here's a link to more info about the bug fixed in SP1:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/289d0bbb-1d06-4856-9c66-8d3e540d7be9/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts

Answer (score 1):

You can build the **INSERT** statement programatically by fetching the column info from the information_schema where each row of data describes a column:

```
SELECT   table_name, 
         ordinal_position, 
         column_name, 
         data_type, 
         is_nullable, 
         character_maximum_length 
FROM     information_schema.columns 
WHERE    table_name LIKE '%TableName%' 
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

For exporting data BCP is the tool and the BOL has several decent examples:

`bcp AdventureWorks.Sales.Currency out Currency.dat -T -c`

Answer (score -1):

You can run a insert script generator like [this one](http://sqltips.wordpress.com/category/insert-script-generator/)

or a desktop tool like this [link](https://github.com/sytelus/SQLUtils)